# what does it mean by "blur a form control"

Tags: angular

This is from angular document:
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation
When the user blurs the form control element, the control is marked as "touched"

I want to ask what does it mean by "blur"?

Comment: Perhaps this article could help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an event that is fired off when an element has lost focus. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event).

This happens when you interact with an element, and then click or tab somewhere else and the element "loses" focus.

Comment: From an English standpoint, if something is no longer in "focus", then it is "blurry". Hence, "blur". That's what helps me remember.